# How to show that if $f$ measurable, therefore $g$ define by $g(x,y)=f(x)$ is also measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ a measure on a space $X$ s.t. $\mu(X)<\infty $ and let $f:X\to\mathbb R$ measurable. Show that $g:X\times X\to\mathbb R$ define by $g(x,y)=f(x)$ is measurable.

I know that 
$$\{x\in X\mid f(x)<\alpha\}$$
for all $\alpha$ is measurable, can I conclude that 
$$\{(x,y)\in X\times Y\mid g(x,y)=f(x)<\alpha\}$$
is measurable for all $\alpha$ ? I would like to say yes, but I don't really know why. My first Idea would be to show that $g$ is integrable.
$$I:=\iint_{X\times X}|g(x,y)|d\mu(x)d\mu(y)=\iint_{X\times X}|f(x)|d\mu(x)d\mu(y)$$
we know that $f$ is measurable, therefore, by Fubini's theorem
$$I=\underbrace{\int_X d\mu(y)}_{=\mu(X)<\infty}\underbrace{\int_X |f(x)|d\mu(x)}_{<\infty }<\infty $$

therefore the function $g$ is integrable and so measurable.

**Questions:**

**1)** Is my proof correct ? and if not, why ?

**2)** If we would have $\mu(X)=\infty $ how we could conclude ?

**3)** Is there an other method to conclude ? (with out compute an integral)

**4)** And finally, do we have $$\text{integrable}\iff\text{mesurable}\ \ \ ?$$
The implication is obvious, but I'm not sure about the reciprocal.

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be $\mu$-measurable and is $g$ supposed to be $\mu \times \mu$-measurable?

Comment: of course ! we are in $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$

Comment: I think by assuming that you can define the integral of $g$, you have assumed that it is measurable. Also, is $y$ being fixed? For your last question, absolutely not. Take any constant function on an infinite measure space. It's measurable, but not integrable. If you're on the finite measure space $(0,1)$, take $f(x) = 1/x$ with Lebesgue measure, for example. It's not integrable, but it's continuous and thus measurable.

Comment: ok, I see. There is no reason that $y$ is fixed... but $g$ doesn't depend of $y$, therefore it's probably not important.

Comment: Nevermind. It should actually be $(x,y) \in X \times X$ above.

Answer (score 1):

We use that:

$f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is measurable $\iff \forall A\in \mathbb{R}\space,\space A$ measurable $\implies f^{-1}(A)$ measurable in $X$.

Let $A$ be measurable in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $g^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(A)\times X$. Since $f$ is measurable we know that $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}$ and we know use that $\mu(X)<\infty$ to see that $X$ is measurable and now use the result that the product of two measurable sets is measurable. So $g^{-1}(A)$ is measurable and hence g is a measurable function.

Comment: Thanks, but is my proof correct ?

Comment: Agree with danielson's comment that you define whether a measurable function is integrable. The logic doesn't seem right showing that a function is measurable by showing it is integrable.